# SQLite.NET to EF, 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I use 'SQLite-1.0.66.0-setup.exe' from http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/.
I have a db of 'World.db3' with 3 tables `City`, `Country`, `CountryLanguage`.
I use VS2008 to generate a `demo.edmx` from that db.

But in the programming:

`WorldEntities we = new WorldEntities();` is right.

`WorldEntities.City city = new WorldEntities.City();` is error.

It says:

`'WorldEntities.City' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'`.

But I can see the `City` in `demo.Designer.cs`.

`public partial class WorldEntities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`

`public partial class City : global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorldEntities`  is your context, the `City` is a property on that object.

Remove the prefix "WorldEntities." and add the appropriate namespace for the type City.

eg.

```
ModelNamespace.City city = new ModelNamespace.City();
```

Comment: You're right. I screwed up between different namespaces due to 'stupid' naming conventions. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

WorldEntities is a class not a namespace so you need to write:

```
WorldEntities we = new WorldEntities();
we.City = new City();
```

Comment: That's incorrect since the we.City is a badly named collection of cities in the OP's case

Comment: Bad naming convention on the part of the OP doesn't make my answer incorrect, especially given that wasn't part of the question.